# Unable to implement VB interface in C# because of constraints error

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I can't figure this out and I don't know why. Sorry is this bad question, I have the following interface in VB

```
Public Interface IFoo  

    Sub ExecuteSQL(sql As String, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter)
    Sub ExecuteSQL(sql As String, useTransaction As Boolean, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter)
    Function ExecuteSQLAsync(sql As String, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) As Task
    Function ExecuteSQLAsync(sql As String, useTransaction As Boolean, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) As Task
    Function ExecuteSQL(Of T As Structure)(sql As String, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) As T
    Function ExecuteSQL(Of T As Structure)(sql As String, useTransaction As Boolean, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) As T
    Function ExecuteSQLAsync(Of T As Structure)(sql As String, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) As Task(Of T)
    Function ExecuteSQLAsync(Of T As Structure)(sql As String, useTransaction As Boolean, ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) As Task(Of T)

End Interface
```

When I implement the interface in C# I get the following error.

> The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method ExecuteSQL(string, bool, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]) must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method IFoo.ExecuteSQL(string, bool, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[])'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead

This is the C# implemenation of the interface. Not sure why I get that error when I use:

> where T : struct

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public T ExecuteSQL<T>(string sql, bool useTransaction, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : struct
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T ExecuteSQL<T>(string sql, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : struct
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ExecuteSQL(string sql, bool useTransaction, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ExecuteSQL(string sql, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<T> ExecuteSQLAsync<T>(string sql, bool useTransaction, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : struct
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<T> ExecuteSQLAsync<T>(string sql, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : struct
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task ExecuteSQLAsync(string sql, bool useTransaction, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task ExecuteSQLAsync(string sql, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That does seem odd. The explicit implementation compiles though -  `T IFoo.ExecuteSQL<T>(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)`

Comment: I've just tried this and it works fine, I think we must be missing something else.

Comment: @stuartd I understand that but why do I need to do implict Implementation on generic method. I have other methods that are not generic and I'm able to implement the interface with no problem. Also if I change the method from ExecuteSQL(Of T) without the restriction work with no problem

Comment: @DavidG good idea let me isolate the issue.

Comment: Your updated code still works for my by the way.

Comment: I just isolate the issue and still get the same error

Comment: @DavidG So that code compiles for you without the explicit interface? Which VS version are you using?

Comment: @stuartd Yeah, copied in verbatim. VS2015

Comment: More info: VB class library and C# console app in same solution, both .Net4.6, C# project references the VB project, copy in the code, add `using VbProject;` line, compile, celebrate my victory!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VB and C# compilers generate different IL when constraining the generic type parameter to value types (note the additional `.ctor ([mscorlib]System.ValueType` constraint that the C# compiler generates).

VB:

```
instance !!T ExecuteSQL<valuetype T>(string sql,
              bool useTransaction,
              class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters) cil managed
```

C#:

```
instance !!T ExecuteSQL<valuetype .ctor ([mscorlib]System.ValueType) T>(string sql,
              bool useTransaction,
              class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameters) cil managed
```

The different method signatures result in the mismatch that is indicated by the error message.

I think to have the VB compiler generate something similar you would have to add a `New` constraint as well - which is not allowed by the compiler. Consequently, as far as I see, there is no way around explicitly implementing that interface.

(I checked this using the C# 5 compiler, not using the new Roslyn compiler of VS 2015 which might behave differently)

#### Update

As pointed out by @Luisgrs the new Roslyn VB compiler included with VS 2015 now generates the generic constraint the same way as the C# compiler does. So one solution would be to update your compiler / Visual Studio version.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting - when Resharper auto-implements the VB interface in the question it adds `Of T As {Structure, ValueType})` - which doesn't compile.

Comment: I don't get why C# compiler will add `ctor ([mscorlib]System.ValueType)` when the `T` is a `struct

Comment: Why does his code work fine for me then? I'm confused!

Comment: @DavidG: I suspect using the Roslyn compiler of VS 2015 makes the difference.

Comment: in vs2015 they used Rosalyn compiler, in 2013 they use the old compiler, if you open the solution in vs2013 it will break.

Comment: @DirkVollmar I tried it in VS2013 too - is that enough to force C#5?

Comment: In VS2015 VB code is now compiled like C#:
`instance !!T  ExecuteSQL<valuetype .ctor ([mscorlib]System.ValueType) T>...`

Comment: @Luizgrs: Thanks, I don't have the current compiler available right now.